# C# Tcp Connection to Unity Android Apk

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, tcp

I have a tcp connection program. There are client and server sides. Client sides file is working on unity as script. Server sides file is working on main pc and as desktop application. When I open server and client files, they work on pc. If I also seperate this files to different pc's  and again , they work. Up to here there is no any problem. However, if I want to build this client sides script file -which is on unity- as android apk and move it to my mobile device, client sides file is working but not connect to server. On computers, there is no any error, but apk file has error.

C# Server Side Code--

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    //public virtual System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles Anchor { get; set; }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Starting TCP and UDP servers on port {0}...", 27015));

        devices_battery_midlow_pic_1.Visible = false;
        devices_battery_low_pic_1.Visible = false;
        devices_battery_midhigh_pic_1.Visible = false;
        devices_battery_high_pic_1.Visible = false;

        play_button.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom);

        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Getting IP...");
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPAddress ipAddress2 = ipHostInfo.AddressList[1];
        connection_id_label.Text = "This IP:\n" + ipAddress2.MapToIPv4().ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Starting Connection Thread...");

        connectionThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartServer));
        connectionThread.IsBackground = true;
        connectionThread.Start();


    }

    private void StartServer()
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 27015);
        listener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            using (TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient())
            {
                using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                    int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
                    string dataReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Received: {dataReceived}");
                    //Thread staThread = new Thread(() => PasteText(dataReceived));
                    //staThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                    //staThread.Start();
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

Client Side C# Script--

```
void Start()
{

    Debug.Log(string.Format("Starting TCP and UDP clients on port {0}...", 116));
    //udpThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ClientThread));
    //udpThread.Start();

    ClientThread();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}

void OnGUI()
{
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 10, 150, 100), debugString))
    {
        print("You clicked the button!");
    }
}

void ClientThread()
{
    using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient("10.10.10.73", 27015))
    {
        using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
        {
            byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("asdasd");
            stream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
        }
    }
 }
```

It is too important for me. I'm waiting your help.

Comment: Do you know which error? If so could you post it as well please?

Comment: actually i dont get any error. When I start the apk file, it starts but not connect to server application.

Comment: check from device log https://answers.unity.com/questions/492681/how-to-use-adb-logcat.html i'm guessing its IP address issue, if you use that fixed value there for tcpclient

Answer (score 0):

below is some connection demo from my other projects. It works on Android/iOS/Mac/PC without issue & tested. I used Loom for easy threading, you may grab it from somewhere github maybe.

or maybe just the way you type IP. It should be sth like this.

```
string IP = "127.0.0.1";
client.BeginConnect(IPAddress.Parse(IP), ClientListenPort, ClientEndConnect, null);
```

This is my working server listener:

```
//create listener
        listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, ClientListenPort);
        listener.Start();
        listener.Server.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

Loom.RunAsync(() => {
                while (!stop)
                {
                    // Wait for client connection
                    clients.Add(listener.AcceptTcpClient());
                    clients[clients.Count - 1].NoDelay = true;
                    // We are connected
                    isConnected = true;

                    streams.Add(clients[clients.Count - 1].GetStream());
                    streams[streams.Count - 1].WriteTimeout = 500;

                    Loom.QueueOnMainThread(() => {
                        isConnected = true;
                    });
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
                }
            });
```

This is my working client demo connection:

```
Loom.RunAsync(() => {
        // if using the IPAD
        //client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(IP), ClientListenPort);
        client.BeginConnect(IPAddress.Parse(IP), ClientListenPort, ClientEndConnect, null);
        while (!client.Connected)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
        }

        //do sth...
    });

void ClientEndConnect(IAsyncResult result)
{
    client.EndConnect(result);
}
```